# How I can save git commit messages to the file?

Tags: git, unix

want to commit, fix errors and send changes them to the GIT repository, but the number of messages exceeds the number of rows displayed in the Unix command line so I cant read error messages. How can I save GIT commit messages to the file or possibly increase the number of lines displayed on the Unix command line?

It seems that in this GIT build uses hooks, it shows messages like:

```
/usr/local/scripts/act check test-file --file-www/htdocs/doms/netflow/scripts/read.php --verbose
Logging output to toLogs
[ OK ]   php lint for /www/htdocs/doms/netflow/scripts/read.php - no errors
[ OK ]   code-wrangler audit-php for /www/htdocs/doms/netflow/scripts/read.php - no errors
[ OK ]   No Errors Detected
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "commit messages"? Are you using `git log`? If so, you can scroll down with `j`, or you can output it to a file with `git log > log.txt`

Comment: I updated my question, I apologize for not giving all the information at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For redirecting stdout and stderr for a git command, you can do:

```
git commit -m "your message" 2>&1 | cat >> log &
```

(as suggested in "[Trying to redirect 'git gc' output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18002585/6309)")
Or:

```
script -q -c 'git commit -m "your message"' > log
script -q -c 'git commit -m "your message"' | sed 's/\r.*//g' > log
```

---

You can try and desactivate the pager to make sure to get the full log

```
 git --no-pager log --decorate=short --pretty=oneline > alog.txt
 # or
 GIT_PAGER="cut -c 1-${COLUMNS-80}" git log
```

See more at "[How to make git log not prompt to continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7736781/6309)"

(This differs from the pager settings you can set for long lines, as in "[git diff - handling long lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103533/6309)")

Comment: Thanks for answer! --no-pager is not working, but i think it is expected, because I use `git commit`, not `git log`.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov Ok, it is more a redirection issue, then. I have edited my answer.