# Python subprocess "git gc" stderr is not captured

Tags: python, git, subprocess

Here's my observed behavior:

```
>>> out = subprocess.check_output("git gc", shell=True)
Counting objects: 4869, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1219/1219), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4869/4869), done.
Total 4869 (delta 3607), reused 4869 (delta 3607)
```

The operation output is printed in `STDERR`. I wanted to capture this one in a variable too so I sent stderr to `STDOUT`. But it does not capture it.

```
>>> out = subprocess.check_output("git gc", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>>> out
b''
>>> print(out)
b''
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

It seems that [git gc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002585/trying-to-redirect-git-gc-output) is a special case where output redirection is not possible. Using typescript was recommended in the other question, but can someone with more knowledge explain that behavior? The script approach did not work as it did not exit the fork.

Comment: Which python version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to redirect 'git gc' output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002585/trying-to-redirect-git-gc-output)

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`git gc` is really a special case, see here:
[Trying to redirect 'git gc' output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002585/trying-to-redirect-git-gc-output)

Try using `git status` to see the difference.

### Update

The question was a nice challenge. A co-worker looked at the source code of GIT and found out that `git gc` only writes to `stdout` if the process is not started in background. After some searching I came across the [pty library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pty.html) and inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953572/2776376 found a working solution.
 The following code catches the `stdout` of `git gc`, although it has to be written to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import pty
import sys

log_name = 'git_log.txt'

def git_logger():
    (child_pid, fd) = pty.fork()
    if child_pid == 0:
        #parent process
        sys.stdout.flush()
        os.execlp("git", "git", "gc")
    else:
        #child process
        output = os.read(fd, 100)
        while True:
            try:
                output += os.read(fd, 1024)
            except:
                break
        with open(log_name, 'w') as log_file:
            log_file.write(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    git_logger()
    with open(log_name, 'r') as log_file:
        print(log_file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

[`git gc` may change its behavior depending whether its standard input/output/error streams are connected to a terminal or not (whether it thinks, it is run interactively or not)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18006967/4279). If you want the same output as if you were running it in the terminal; you could use a pseudo-tty (it seems there is no command-line option that would configure the desired output behavior for `git gc`: `--quiet` doesn't accept a parameter e.g., like it does with `apt-get`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

output, exitstatus = pexpect.run('git gc', withexitstatus=1)
```

Related questions with `pty`-based solutions:

- [Last unbuffered line can't be read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25923901/4279)
- [Python subprocess readlines() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12419198/4279)